# "this is undefined" in nested return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass some props `mapObject={this.props.mapObject} details={this.props.parsedData.categories[key]` through to another  another component `Item` but I am getting `TypeError: this is undefined`

The props are passed through correctly as I am able to access them  on the first line where I am calling `mapObject`. It is only in the nested `return` that I can't seem to access them. My code is below.

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.mapObject(this.props.parsedData.categories, function (key, value) {
                return (
                    <div id="dropdown">
                        <div id="category-cirle"><center>{key[0].toUpperCase() + key[1]}</center></div>
                        <div id="dropdown-content">
                            <Item key={key} mapObject={this.props.mapObject} details={this.props.parsedData.categories[key]} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })
        );
    }
}
```

How do I pass the props through to `Item`?

Comment: you could use a fat arrow function (it automatically bind this). Instead of `, function(key, value)` try using `, (key, value) =>`

Comment: `this` is kind of special in javascript. The following link help me a lot understanding javascript better: https://maximdenisov.gitbooks.io/you-don-t-know-js/content/this_&_object_prototypes/this_or_that.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `function` as the second argument of `mapObjects`, so `this` in the function is not referring to your component class. Try using arrow syntax instead, which will retain the context of `this`:

```js
this.props.mapObjects(this.props.parsedData.categories, (key, value) => {
    return ...
});
```